# Chunk generation algorithm/code

Tags: java, voxel

So basically i'm trying to make a 'voxel world' Generator (I use the term voxel VERY losely, more of just a box). i've got so far as to make a `createChunk();` method, it basically just uses the `createVoxel()` method and a for loop to place it a few times, incrementing it's X by 1 each time.

I want to know if there is a way to make this easier and more randomized, using `noise` i believe might help? but i cannot figure out how to use this, so can someone please shed some light on my complication?

Thank you :)

Comment: i think this might prove useful to you - http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/16563/how-are-voxel-terrain-engines-made